# Migrate schema's specific objects between dbs in Snowflake

Tags: database, database-migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My `ARCHIVE` db in Snowflake already has `SCHEMA_X`. Few days ago new objects got added to `SCHEMA_X` in `PROD` db. What would be good practice to move only new/changed objects rather then entire schema to `ARCHIVE` db?

My plan is as follows:

1. SQL query to define new elements in `PROD` db.
2. SQL query to compare existing objects in both schemas for differences.
3. Clone results from above points to `ARCHIVE`

Any one has more automated approach maybe?

Comment: Hi - are the 2 DBs currently completely separate or is there a "connection" between them e.g. ARCHIVE was originally created by cloning PROD? Do you just want to replicate the  new object structures in ARCHIVE or do you also want to populate them? If you want to populate them is this with a complete copy of what is in PROD or some subset of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone the entire schema that should be quick and upto date.
Note- Cloning does not clones external tables n internal stages.

Answer (score 1):

I would say entire schema is better - because problems start when on top of adding objects you would end up modifying for example. If you're only storing the structure, not the data itself, the space needed to store that is pretty much none compared to the actual data (unless you end up changing the schema every 10 minutes)